# Prevent duplicate values from userform to table column

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, userform

I have a userform to enter customer information into a table.  I have this to prevent entry of customers with no name:

```
If CBCustName.Text = "" Then

   MsgBox "Nothing to Add.  Enter Customer Information.", vbOKOnly, "Enter Customer Data"

   CBCustName.SetFocus
   Exit Sub
End If
```

I would also like to see if the customer already exists (column A of the table CustInfo), and display a message box telling the user duplicates aren’t allowed.  Customer names are entered into combo box CBCustName.

This routine is initiated by a command button CmdAddNewCust.  After these two checks are run, it should write all of the data the user input to the control to the appropriate row/column of the table.  I have this to do that part, and it seems to work ok:

```
Set tblRow = CustInfoTable.ListRows

tblRow.Range(1, 1).Value = CBCustName.Value
tblRow.Range(1, 2).Value = TxtAddress.Value
tblRow.Range(1, 3).Value = TxtCity.Value
tblRow.Range(1, 4).Value = TxtState.Value
tblRow.Range(1, 5).Value = TxtZip.Value
tblRow.Range(1, 6).Value = TxtPhone.Value
tblRow.Range(1, 7).Value = TxtContact.Value
tblRow.Range(1, 8).Value = TxtULRate.Value
tblRow.Range(1, 9).Value = TxtLRate.Value
tblRow.Range(1, 10).Value = TxtStandby.Value
tblRow.Range(1, 11).Value = TxtFuelSCharge.Value
```

I’ve tried modifying several code snippets, but I’m missing something.  Can anyone point me in the right direction to prevent duplicate entries?  As always, your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pre-search the range with customers and check if the customer name already exists there, something like:

```
dim rngCust as range

set rngCust = thisworkbook.sheets("SheetName").Range("A:A").Find(CustomerName) 

if rngCust is nothing then     
   addCustomer    
else    
   msgbox "Customer already exists"    
end if
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you cyboashu.  I modified your code to work with a table:      "Set rngCust = CustInfoSheet.ListObjects("CustInfo").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Find(CustName)"  and that works perfectly!  Thank you again for taking time to help.

Comment: Oh, sorry Markos.  I have been trying to find an answer for this for a couple days.  Many thanks!